# Unity 2D: Sprites/Diffuse is making my character weird, like an antialias

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, lighting

i'm trying to put light and shadows on my 2D character but when i set the material on it to Sprites/Diffuse, it's kinda putting a strange smooth on my pixels.

Without diffuse:

[image: Without dif]

With diffuse:

[image]

And i saw that with diffuse it doesn't appear any shadow, it's normal?

Comment: Completely normal. casting shadows is a property of lights. Set them there. Diffuse lighting will work like this. If you are using point lights, try using directional lights instead( is it called sun in unity?)

Comment: I used point lights just to test, the sun lights is the directional if i'm not wrong. The problem isn't just the light, if you notice, when i use the diffuse property, it does kinda an anti alias to my character, that make it weird

Comment: The lighting is calculated per pixel/vertex, so the pixels of the sprite that are further from the light receive less light and are darker. No anti-aliasing here.

Comment: No, i don't want the antialias, look at the pixels from the diffuse image, and without the diffuse. With the diffuse the engine tries to smooth the pixels and make what i don't want

Comment: Looks more like z fighting than anything color related. How are you drawing this? Just a quad?

Comment: It's a empty game object with the sprites inside, and they're set in different layers.

Comment: Try turning off culling to see if it goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found how to fix. You have to recreate the project, and then before put all the sprites together, you have to unmark Generate MipMaps and change filter mode to point. Do this without creating a new project(inside of the project already done) didn't worked. Then after replacing all the slices, you put the material with Sprites/Diffuse.